# What does RELEASE_SAFELY mean and why does it not work in xcode4?

Tags: xcode, release, xcode4

what does `RELEASE_SAFELY` or `RELEASE_CF_SAFELY` mean? Ok, it's for releasing objects but why not use `[obj release]`?

Besides I tried to use it in xcode 4 but I am running into buid errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_RELEASE_SAFELY", referenced from:
      -[AdressBookModel search:] in AdressBookModel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can I do just `[obj release]` instead? What would you consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RELEASE_SAFELY is not a function but a macro and is usually defined like this:

```
#define RELEASE_SAFELY(__POINTER) { [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil; }
```

(I think it's not part of the SDK but has to be declared in each project separately. And I don't think it has anything to do with the XCode version.)

So it first calls *release* and then additionally sets the variable to *nil*. That's good practice because it prevents double releases or access to a deallocated instance.

It seems that your code believes it's a function (instead of a macro). Probably the compiler warns you that it hasn't been declared.

The fix is to put the above macro definition in an appropriate header file.