# Error Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_RELEASE_SAFELY", referenced from:

Tags: ios, iphone, compiler-errors, linker-errors

> Ld
>   /Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vocab-cieqpeybobkktaberajtbzmxptpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Vocab.app/Vocab
>   normal armv7
>       cd "/Users/macmini2/Desktop/utkal/LAnguage_forest14/Language_Forest/Vocabulary
>   Tutor/Vocab"
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vocab-cieqpeybobkktaberajtbzmxptpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/macmini2/Desktop/utkal/LAnguage_forest14/Language_Forest/Vocabulary\
>   Tutor/Vocab/Airship
>   -L/Users/macmini2/Desktop/utkal/LAnguage_forest14/Language_Forest/Vocabulary\
>   Tutor/Vocab
>   -F/Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vocab-cieqpeybobkktaberajtbzmxptpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/macmini2/Desktop/utkal/LAnguage_forest14/Language_Forest/Vocabulary\
>   Tutor/Vocab/../iOS\ Framework
>   -F/Users/macmini2/Desktop/utkal/LAnguage_forest14/Language_Forest/Vocabulary\
>   Tutor/Vocab/../iOS\ Framework -filelist
>   /Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vocab-cieqpeybobkktaberajtbzmxptpx/Build/Intermediates/Vocab.build/Debug-iphoneos/Vocab.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Vocab.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -ObjC -lz -all_load -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework MapKit -lUAirship-2.1.0 -lUAirship-2.1.0 -framework Social -framework CoreData -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework StoreKit -framework
>   CoreTelephony -lz -lOAuth-ios6 -framework MobileCoreServices
>   -framework MediaPlayer -framework Security -lxml2 -framework QuartzCore -framework MessageUI -framework AVFoundation -framework
>   AudioToolbox -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreText
>   -lsqlite3 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework WordnikUI -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vocab-cieqpeybobkktaberajtbzmxptpx/Build/Intermediates/Vocab.build/Debug-iphoneos/Vocab.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Vocab_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/macmini2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vocab-cieqpeybobkktaberajtbzmxptpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Vocab.app/Vocab
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_RELEASE_SAFELY",
>   referenced from:
>         -[VocabViewController dealloc] in VocabViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

- I am getting this error ,i  dont know what does it mean i googled a
  lot but not getting any solution.
- I am going to submit my app and using libUAirship 1.1.2.a which
  causes error Of UDID and apple failed validation.
- SO download latest libUariship 2.1.0.a and after implemetaion of that
  i am getting this error.Help me.

Comment: Show the declaration of `RELEASE_SAFELY`.

Comment: do you enable ARC in your projcet

Comment: @iDev no, this project was build in xcode 4.5 and now i am using xcode5 so what do you think occurance of error is  relevance with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does RELEASE\_SAFELY mean and why does it not work in xcode4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420589/what-does-release-safely-mean-and-why-does-it-not-work-in-xcode4)

Answer (score 0):

i tought its coming from xCode version and the macro defined. because RELEASE_SAFELY is not a function.

```
#define RELEASE_SAFELY(__POINTER) { [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil; }
```

[source link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420589/what-does-release-safely-mean-and-why-does-it-not-work-in-xcode4) this help you more